# How to make all rows and columns have auto equal size in an array/matrix?

Tags: matrices, arrays, alignment

I have nested matrix, but I want it to have equal sized rows and columns. But I don't want to specify the size parameters, I want the size to be auto-adjustable, to be the size of the biggest element in a matrix.

How can I do this?

```latex
  \documentclass[12pt]{article}
  \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
  \usepackage[russian]{babel}
  \usepackage{amssymb}
  \usepackage{systeme}
  \usepackage{amsmath}
  \usepackage{amsthm}
  \usepackage{graphicx}
  \usepackage{mathtools}
  \usepackage{bbold}
  \usepackage{enumitem}
  \usepackage{collectbox}
  \usepackage{multicol}
  \usepackage[margin=0.5in]{geometry}
  \usepackage{tabularx}
  \usepackage[scr=boondoxo,scrscaled=1.05]{mathalfa}
  \usepackage{stackengine}
  \usepackage{wrapfig}


  \setlength{\parindent}{0ex}
  \linespread{1.2}

  \begin{document}
  $
          \left(\begin{array}{c|c}
                          \begin{matrix}
                                  \lambda-t & 0\\0 & \lambda - t
                          \end{matrix} & A^2\\
                          \hline
                          0 & A^3 - tE_{n-k}
          \end{array}\right)
  $
  \end{document}
```

Comment: your example is not very clear (and includes many unrelated packages which makes it slower and harder to test answers)  which entries should have the same width, for the outer matrix do you mean A^2 should be as wide as the inner matrix? or do you mean that all 7 cells with non-matrix math expressions are all equal width?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This solution measures the size of the largest entry (the matrix) and uses a `\rule` to match the height and a `\mathmakebox` to match the width.

I commented out all irrelevant packages.

```
  \documentclass[12pt]{article}
  %\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
  %\usepackage[russian]{babel}
  %\usepackage{amssymb}
  %\usepackage{systeme}
  %\usepackage{amsmath}
  %\usepackage{amsthm}
  %\usepackage{graphicx}
  \usepackage{mathtools}
 %\usepackage{bbold}
 %\usepackage{enumitem}
 %\usepackage{collectbox}
 %\usepackage{multicol}
 \usepackage[margin=0.5in]{geometry}
 % \usepackage{tabularx}
 %\usepackage[scr=boondoxo,scrscaled=1.05]{mathalfa}
 %\usepackage{stackengine}
 %\usepackage{wrapfig}


  \setlength{\parindent}{0ex}
  \linespread{1.2}

  \begin{document}
  \bgroup
  \sbox0{$\begin{matrix}
      \lambda-t & 0\\0 & \lambda - t
    \end{matrix}$}% biggest entry
  $
          \left(\begin{array}{c|c}
                          \begin{matrix}
                                  \lambda-t & 0\\0 & \lambda - t
                          \end{matrix} & A^2\\
                          \hline
                          \rule[-\dp0]{0pt}{\dimexpr \ht0+\dp0}% create strut
                          0 & \mathmakebox[\wd0]{A^3 - tE_{n-k}}
          \end{array}\right)
  $
  \egroup
  \end{document}
```

Comment: Wow that worked! Thank you vert much)! Sorry that I put tons of unused packages. That was my first question on this platform)